# Should I turn my SQLite class into a singleton?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, singleton, android-sqlite

I'm in the middle of creating an Android application with multiple tables inside of my database. The database is going to be constantly accessed, but with that said I've stumbled upon the idea of a singleton from http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html

Would it be advised to try to make a database a singleton so that I never have conflicts?

EDIT: In response to the first comment. I have an SQLiteOpenHelper class that I believe I can structure into a singleton.

Comment: What do you mean database? A class that manages your connections? Or something else? A database cannot be made a singleton..... Well not in the way you mean it at least.

Comment: What does SQLiteOpenHelper do?

Comment: "A helper class to manage database creation and version management." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application and design. You can make a class singleton if it only creates a database. 
But if you make singleton a class which executes query, you have to make sure that it doesn't gets called while the first query is executing. So a locking mechanism or queuing will be required then.

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` creates a database once. My question is targeted towards how DB commands are queued up in SQLite in Android.

Comment: They're not queued up by default. I think you have to Queue them yourself if required.